# Cant find module "../encodings"

Tags: node.js, express

When I try and make a request to my server I get the following:
Error: Cannot find module '../encodings'

https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/issues/118 This is the same issue I face but nothing recommended on there works.

My project was working fine, then I moved the project folder to a different location and thats when the issue started. So I moved it back but the issue persisted. I cannot work on my project as this issue prevents me.

I tried removing node_modules and reinstalling but was unsuccesfull.

This is the line of code in question:

```
iconv.encodings = require("../encodings");
```

That path does exist and I can see it. I dont know whats wrong.

Its been days and I have not been able to find any solutions anywhere.

I am a beginner. Please let me know if I need to provide anything else that can aid.

[image: Project structure]

[image: Showing encoding location]

Comment: https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/issues/118#issuecomment-267811928 does not work ?!

Comment: No. It did not work.

Comment: How does your project structure looks like ?

Comment: In the project folder I have my server.js and all my server side code. Then I have a folder titled "client" in which I ran create-react-app and have all front end code. Its a MERN app.  Im sorry if i did not explain that correctly.

Comment: Can you please create a screenshot, a "tree dump" or a ascii art of your structure

Comment: added images to my original post

Comment: Just to verify `iconv.encodings = require("iconv-lite/encodings");` really does not work?

Comment: No. I tried it again by copying it directly from your comment and then stopping/running the server again. Still get error.

Comment: Hmm, that should work. what version of npm/node are you using ? What is your cwd when you start the app ? is this the only package with a require problem ? What happens when you move the `iconv.encodings = require(...)` on top of the file ?

Comment: npm v- 6.14.8  node v-12.19.0.  Im sorry, what is the cwd? Does that mean current working directory? Its the same as the location of the server.js file. Yes this is the only package with the problem. Can I move the that line to the top? That line is part of an if statement thats in a function. Do i move the entire function? Sorry, again i am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was just creating a new project and copying over all of the files from the project in question. Everything then began to work correctly.